# Make temporarily copy of specific activeMQ queue to count the number of messages?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Due to memory constraint, activeMQ only returns a snapshot of the queue and does not guarantee all the messages while iterating over it.

In order to count all the messages, with one of it's property matching a specific value, I thought of making a copy of the queue (without consuming the messages). Once a temporary copy is made, I can start consuming the messages from this temporary queue and count all the messages matching the property. This way the original queue will remain unaffected.

Is it possible to make a copy of an queue without consuming messages from it? Are there any drawback of it?

Mirrored queues, Virtual Topics and Composite Destinations would not be helpful as it would forward all the messages to another queue and not make copy of an existing queue.

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems rather overkill given what you want is simply to get a count of the messages in the queue which is easily achievable using the [JMX MBeans](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx) for the Queue statistics.  You can access the MBeans using the [Jolokia powered](https://activemq.apache.org/rest) Rest APIs as well.

If you are dead set against JMX then you could leverage the [statistics broker plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin) to allow a message based API to access broker statistics.

Comment: I want to get count of messages that was added to the queue within a certain time frame. Not the count of the entire messages in the Queue.

Comment: @ChetanParakh -- JMX records enqueue/dequeue counts, as well as total size. You could compare the enqueue count at two points in time. Trying to copy the queue -- even it that were possible -- isn't going to solve your problem unless you can copy it instantly.

Comment: @ChetanParakh sounds like you want to treat the broker as a database, which it most certainly is not.